# How come Firestore work without internet permissions?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a working Firestore project. I read and write, and things work well but the main issue is that all of this is working without Internet permissions. I have one permission only for audio recording.

How can that possibly be happening ?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx">

    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AuthActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewNoteActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Firestore / RecycleView init:

```
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(this, options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize( true );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this ) );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: show the code and manifest

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: Newer API levels of Android grant internet permission explicitly without requiring it in the manifest.  This is the new normal situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle dependencies are also Java/Kotlin Android applications, meaning they have their own Manifests.

When you build with Gradle, it merges all your Manifests, including all the ones in your implementations. That means Firebase's Manifest is merged into yours.

Most libraries define the permissions they use in their own Manifests, so you don't have to include them yourself, and Firebase is like most libraries, so it includes the INTERNET permission in its Manifest.

When you compile your project, the Firestore Manifest is merged into yours, so your app now requests the INTERNET permission.

Comment: That is the correct answer ! I observed the manifest file using ManifestReader app and it shows the internet permissions. Thanks.